# Fast way to ask Siri to start a "Breathe" session in the Mindfulness app on Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, siri

The [*Mindfulness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness_(Apple)) app on the Apple Watch (watchOS 9.2) offers two modes, one of them is *Breathe*.

Is there a quick way to ask Siri to start a *Breathe* session, rather than tap-tap-tap my way to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### "Hey Siri, open Mindfulness app„

I don't think there are any commands to start "Breathe" directly from the Mindfulness app. But the command above will open the app, so you can start it from there.

#### "Hey Siri, open Breathe app„

An alternative and more efficient way to start Breathe is to use the [Breathe](https://apps.apple.com/app/breathe/id1459455352) app (Apple-made).

Again, you will still need to tap to start, but this will reduce the amount of tip-tapping you need to do. With the above voice command, you can open the Breathe app directly, and from there, all you have to do is press one button - "Start".